# chromecast "receiver not found" when switching to my appID

Tags: google-cast

I have registered my chromecast in the developer console and after seeing the message ready for testing I restarted it by disonnecting and reconnecting it.

I have cloned the CastHelloText reposetory from github, hosted it on my server, and loaded the sender from my chrome web-browser (with chromecast extention already installed).

So far so good, it connected to my chromecast and broadcasted the messages I wrote in my browser.

Afterwards, I registered an app to get an app ID, as a URL I gave the direct link to where my server is hosting the receiver page - which is unchanged from the repository.

I then changed the `applicationID` varuble in the sender to the one I got. However now, when I refreshed the page, the console shows the following output:

```
Found cast extension: boadgeojelhgndaghljhdicfkmllpafd
chromehellotext.html:173 onInitSuccess
chromehellotext.html:173 receiver list empty
```

Switching it back makes it work again, it finds my device and connects to it.

The only thing that changes is the appID in the sender application.

Why does it not find my device when I'm using my appID? What else can I check?

Answer (score 2):

A few things can be happening. First, how long did you wait after registering your AppId? Reboot your chromecast to make sure it gets the new configuration. Secondly, did you enter the serial number of your chromecast into the Developer Console when you created your App Id? If not, do that and if you have already done that, double check the serial number, I recommend you take a photo of the serial number, zoom in and then read it off since it is very easy to mistake, say, 0 and O, etc.

If after all of these you still have issues, then you can open a support ticket with our [support team](https://support.google.com/cast-developer/contact/google_cast_contact_us?hl=en&rd=1) to get further assistance.

Comment: I didn't wait for long before trying. But I tried again now and it still isn't working (so about 4 hours). I don't see any place in the appID creation to insert to serail number of the device, but I did register the device under the same account I registered the app ID. I also tripled checked the serial number. Is there a way to confirm that my chromecast is indeed registered other than the "ready for testing" message at the developer console? Because I don't see anything different in the chromecast itself

Comment: As I had suggested, please contact our support at the url that I had provided; they would be able to help you further with your issue.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this same issue, registered my app and device, double checked the IDs, got the sample app ID working but my ID only gave the 'receiver list empty', even jumped through some hoops to 'Send this Chromecast's serial number when checking for updates', an option which has been taken out of the app(s).

Uninstalling and reinstalling the Chromecast extension in the browser I was working with did the trick. Once I reinstalled it, without restarting Chrome, I now get 'receiver found' and my receiver app is displaying correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer is late but I just ran into this issue too.  The fix for me was to disable and re-enable the Chromecast extension in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

What @westbyb did above is the key.  You need to uninstall and reinstall the google case extension.  I tried disabling and re-enabling the extension, but it did not fix the problem.

I was experiencing exactly what you describe.

After you re-install, hit ctrl-F5 to get a full refresh.  When I first re-opened the page after re-installing the extension I got the same results as before on the Chromecast.  I checked the dev console.  As before I saw the messages: "onInitSuccess", "receiver list empty" but then followed by "receiver found".  The chromecast still displayed the same mirrored desktop screen as before, but when I refreshed the screen with a ctrl-f5 the receiver displayed properly.